# Не получается установить Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Пытаюсь установить ***webpack***.

Сначала в консоли ввожу команду `npm init`, затем `npm i -D webpack webpack-cli`, начинается установка, после чего выходит следующий список ошибок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Здесь файл с логами](https://dropmefiles.com/5Itz8)

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно и как мне исправить ситуацию?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Попробовал установить как *Администратор*, выдает тоже самое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переименовал названия папок, на английском, тоже не получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке установить через Git Bash аналогичная ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему бы не воспользоваться советом из вывода ошибки? Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

Comment: Grundy, как это сделать?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/968214/open-cmd-as-admin-with-windowsr-shortcut

Comment: Попробовал как администратор, то же самое выдает

Comment: Поменяй название папок, названия должны быть на английском....

Comment: Поменял название папок, на английском тоже не получается

Comment: а что в ...-debug.log ?

Comment: Прикрепил ссылку на файл с логами в описании

Comment: C:\Веб-разработка\mytestproject\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules с этой папкой все в порядке?, он на нее ругается...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй установить для начала Git Bash (https://git-scm.com/), это консоль которой можно и желательно пользоваться вместо windows cmd.

И дальше если ты установил уже node.js, попробуй в папке через консоль (Git Bash) установить пакет webpack снова.

Comment: Попробовал, то же самое, добавил скрин в описание

Comment: Скорее всего это с npm, вот возможное решение:https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17747#issuecomment-328342295

А вообще у многих такая ошибка возникала на винде потестируй решения с этих issues:

1. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17747
2. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17671

И статья краткая есть на medium:
https://medium.com/@dijistanley/fix-for-npm-install-issues-due-to-fsevent-on-windows-19ab7cc98e43